# checkbox value fetch in foreach loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach

With the below given code i am trying to fetch data of check boxes from MySQL database, Which is not working and fetches only last checked value.

With `var_dump($checked);` its giving correct result.

**PHP Script**

```
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];
$team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
if(!empty($_POST['team_id'])) {
        foreach($_POST['team_id'] as $checked) {
            // var_dump($checked);
                $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT a.team, a.player, a.result, a.note, b.category FROM teams a INNER JOIN  groups b ON a.team_id = b.id WHERE a.team_id = :team_id_id AND a.group_id = :group_id ");
                $sql->execute(array(':team_id' => $checked, ':group_id' => $group_id));
        }
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $row1[] = $row;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where you define `$row1` and where you read it out?. And I guess you'll want to move the `while` loop inside the `foreach`. Now the `$sql` variable might not be defined inside your `while` statement

Comment: @jrswgtr I am getting data via ajax, It will be a bit difficult for me to share a bunch of code.

Comment: Then I doubt if we will be able to help you out

Comment: @jrswgtr ok ! i am trying to do it.

Comment: have you var_dump($group_id) ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya This is the result `string(3) "23"` with `var_dump($group_id)` .

Comment: Don't you want the `while` loop to run for every team? Right now it first does all the queries and only after that it will start getting the rows.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Yes because i am selecting teams in checkboxes to display, And every team have multiple players (rows) to be fetched.

Comment: because with in your foreach sends last value. did you try while loop inside foreach?

Comment: @Nawin yes this was the problem,Its working now. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while loop inside `foreach loop` because its causing id problem

```
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];
$team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
if(!empty($_POST['team_id'])) {
    foreach($_POST['team_id'] as $checked) {
            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT a.team, a.player, a.result, a.note, b.category FROM teams a INNER JOIN  groups b ON a.team_id = b.id WHERE a.team_id = :team_id_id AND a.group_id = :group_id ");
            $sql->execute(array(':team_id' => $checked, ':group_id' => $group_id));
    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $row1[] = $row;
    }
}
}
```